# How to install Google Api with cocoa pod

Tags: ios, cocoa, google-api, cocoapods, gmail-api

I'm not able to install google api with cocoa pods

This is my pod:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'testGoogleFacebook' do
    pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
end
```

It install Facebook perfect, but with Google I get this:

```
[!] Error installing Google-API-Client
[!] /usr/local/bin/svn export --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --force http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ -r 422 /var/folders/kk/fyg7f_cx1pxfxh6p377c48rw0000gn/T/d20150907-5479-kgjbk4
```

How can install it? I only need to log in with Google with Gmail scope

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check your SVN version

```
svn --version
```

Mine was 1.6.9

Ended up removing the current version

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/svn'
```

Then installing a newer version

```
brew install subversion
```

It seems to work with the one that was installed 1.8.13

Answer (score 0):

I [found a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-objectivec-client/hnZOY0LwtMc) about the SDK and it seems `Google-API-Client` was never an official pod. 
What you're looking for is the [GoogleAPIClient](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client), which was mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-objectivec-client/BXe5gNzzCzc).